# How to remove not required Elements from generated XML via jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling, unmarshalling

I want to know if there is anyway for removing not required elements from generated xml using jaxb.I have my xsd element definition as follows.

```
           <xsd:element name="Title" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        A name given to the digital record.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:simpleType>
                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:minLength value="1"></xsd:minLength>
                    </xsd:restriction>
                </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
```

As you can see it is not a mandatory element because

> minOccurs="0"

But if it is not empty the length should be 1.

```
<xsd:minLength value="1"></xsd:minLength>
```

At the time of marshalling if I left the Title field blank it is throwing the 
**SAXException** because of min-length restriction.
So what I want to do is to remove the whole occurrence of `<Title/>`
from generated XML.Right now i have removed the min-length restriction so it is adding the `<Title>` element as **EMPTY**

```
<Title></Title>
```

But I do not want it like this.Any help is appreciated.I am using jaxb 2.0 for Marshalling.

**UPDATE:**

Following is my variable definiton :

```
  private JAXBContext jaxbContext;
    private Unmarshaller unmarshaller;
    private SchemaFactory factory;
    private Schema schema;
    private Marshaller marshaller;
```

Marshalling code.

```
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ERecordType.class);
            marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
            schema = factory.newSchema((new File(xsdLocation)));
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            ERecordType e = new ERecordType();
            e.setCataloging(rc);
            /**
             * Validate Against Schema.
             */
            marshaller.setSchema(schema);
            /**
             * Marshal will throw an exception if XML not validated against
             * schema.
             */
            marshaller.marshal(e, System.out);
```

Comment: Post your tried source code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the title value to the empty string `""` it'll generate `<Title/>`, if you set it to `null` it should omit the element entirely.

Comment: Is there a way to make JAXB generate <Title></Title> for empty string? Looks like few parsers are not treating it exactly same as <Title/> .

Comment: @Teddy not that I'm aware of, and since those two forms are identical XML that's a bug in the "few parsers" rather than a problem in JAXB.  It _may_ be possible to work around if you marshal to an XMLStreamWriter and use a StAX implementation that offers this as a configuration option.  I know Woodstox has [some options](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/ConfiguringStreamWriters) that might cover this _if_ JAXB makes separate start/end tag calls to the writer rather than calling `writeEmptyElement`, you'll have to experiment with it yourself and see what works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm exploiting the XmlAdapter, implementing a transparent adapter which return in marshaling the null value if the Collection or String is empty.

```
public class XMLStringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {


    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v != null && v.isEmpty() ? null : v;
    }
}
```

Also add in package-info.java

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
})
your.package
```

https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.6/moxy/advanced_concepts006.htm

[How can JAXB XmlAdapter be used to marshall lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14569293/how-can-jaxb-xmladapter-be-used-to-marshall-lists)