# How can JAXB XmlAdapter be used to marshall lists?

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey, xmladapter

Instances of this class are part of a large object graph and are not at the root of the object graph:

```java
public class Day
{
    public Day(LocalDate date, List<LocalTime> times)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.times = times;
    }

    public Day()
    {
        this(null, null);
    }

    public LocalDate getDate()
    {
        return date;
    }

    public List<LocalTime> getTimes()
    {
        return times;
    }

    private final LocalDate date;

    private final List<LocalTime> times;
}
```

The object graph is converted to JSON using Jersey and JAXB. I have `XmlAdapter`s registered for `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`.

The problem is that it's only working for the `date` property and not the `times` property. I suspect this has something to do with the fact that `times` is a list rather than a single value. How, then, do I tell Jersey/JAXB to marshall each element in the `times` list using the registered `XmlAdapter`?

**Update:**

I confirmed that `LocalTime` marshalling is indeed working for scalar `LocalTime` properties by adding a scalar `LocalTime` property and observing the expected output in the JSON.

For completeness, here's package-info.java:

```java
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalDateAdapter.class, type = LocalDate.class),
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value = LocalTimeAdapter.class, type = LocalTime.class)
})
package same.package.as.everything.else;
```

`LocalDateAdapter`:

```java
public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate>
{
    @Override
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String v) throws Exception
    {
        return formatter.parseLocalDate(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDate v) throws Exception
    {
        return formatter.print(v);
    }

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd");
}
```

`LocalTimeAdapter`:

```java
public class LocalTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalTime>
{
    @Override
    public LocalTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception
    {
        return formatter.parseLocalTime(v);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalTime v) throws Exception
    {
        return formatter.print(v);
    }

    private final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HHmm");
```

Comment: How do you register your `XmlAdapter`s?

Comment: I annotated the package (in package-info.java) in which the POJOs and JAX-RS service are defined with `@XmlAdapters` containing `@XmlAdapter`s for various types including `LocalDate` and `LocalTime`. Like I said, it works perfectly fine for `Day.date` (scalar LocalDate) but not `Day.times` (list of `LocalTime`s). I'm away from my code now, but I'm sure if I tested it with a scalar `LocalTime` property it would work just fine.

Comment: Updated. This proves that the adapters are working for scalars while not working for lists.

Answer (score 5):

An `XmlAdapter` for a class is applied to a mapped field/property of that type, and in the case of collections, for each item in the collection.  The example below proves that this works.  Have you tried running your example standalone to XML to verify the mappings that way.  Is suspect the problem is something else other than the `XmlAdapter` specifically.

**StringAdapter**

The following `XmlAdapter` will convert a `String` to lower case on the unmarshal operation and convert it to upper case when marshalled.

```
package forum14569293;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class StringAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v.toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v.toUpperCase();
    }

}
```

**package-info**

Just as in your question a package level `@XmlJavaTypeAdapters` annotation will be used to register the `XmlAdapter`.  This will register this `XmlAdapter` for all mapped `String` properties within this package (see: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxb-and-package-level-xmladapters.html).

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=StringAdapter.class, type=String.class)
})
package forum14569293;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.*;
```

**Root**

Below is a sample domain model similar to your `Day` class with two mapped properties.  The first is of type `String` and the second `List<String>`.  One thing I notice about your `Day` class is that you only have `get` methods.  This means that you will need to add an `@XmlElement` annotation for a JAXB impl to consider that a mapped property.

```
package forum14569293;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class Root {

    public Root(String foo, List<String> bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }

    public Root() {
        this(null, null);
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public List<String> getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    private final String foo;
    private final List<String> bar;

}
```

**Demo**

```
package forum14569293;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        List<String> bar = new ArrayList<String>(3);
        bar.add("a");
        bar.add("b");
        bar.add("c");
        Root root = new Root("Hello World", bar);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);

    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code we see that all the strings were converted to upper case by the `XmlAdapter`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
    <bar>A</bar>
    <bar>B</bar>
    <bar>C</bar>
    <foo>HELLO WORLD</foo>
</root>
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Thanks. I tried it and the XML consisted of one empty tag only,
>   meaning there's something about the POJO model that JAXB doesn't like.
>   (Perhaps it should be Serializable?)

JAXB does not require that POJOs implement `Serializable`.

> That's interesting because it seems to indicate that the only part
>   JAXB plays in this is to lend its annotations and some other
>   interfaces (e.g. XmlAdapter) to the JSON (de)serializer and that's
>   where the relationship ends.

It depends on what is being used as the JSON binding layer.  The [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) specification does not cover JSON-binding so this type of support is beyond the spec.  EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) offers native JSON-binding (I'm the MOXy lead) with it you could do something like:

```
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
```

And get the following output that takes the `XmlAdapter` into account:

```
{
   "bar" : [ "A", "B", "C" ],
   "foo" : "HELLO WORLD"
}
```

> Nevertheless, when I get an opportunity I will do what I can to get
>   JAXB to generate the XML and that may reveal something else.

This would be useful as I do not believe what you are seeing is a JAXB issue, but an issue in the JSON binding layer that you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and the XML consisted of one empty tag only, meaning there's something about the POJO model that JAXB doesn't like. (Perhaps it should be `Serializable`?) That's interesting because it seems to indicate that the only part JAXB plays in this is to lend its annotations and some other interfaces (e.g. `XmlAdapter`) to the JSON (de)serializer and that's where the relationship ends. Nevertheless, when I get an opportunity I will do what I can to get JAXB to generate the XML and that *may* reveal something else.

Comment: @SteveTaylor - I have updated my answer based on your comment.